# Always load one file with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

I can't get this to work;

It should do these things:
Always load `page.php` (when file does not exists on server). `.include` is an existing folder. When the user visits `.include/...`, then also load `page.php`
My scripts starts with `RewriteEngine On`, but then I'm stuck...
What can I do now to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your post is terribly non-descriptive. Can you provide code samples, elaborate, etc..?

From what I can tell, you might try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php [NC,QSA]
```